# How do I return a collection of dates part of timestamp

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have checked around but can't seem to find a solution to this, which is why I'm asking for help here. 
I am working on a project with Laravel 5.8. I have a mysql table storing customer's orders. The orders table have among other columns ID, order No and a created_at column storing the timestamp of the order.
Now I want to return a collection that contains all the dates there are orders and possibly the number of orders for those dates, returned just once like so;

```
7/10/2019 - 5
6/10/2019 - 6
5/10/2019 - 12
4/10/2019 - 9
```

I want only the date part of the timestamp of the days when there are orders. The days without orders should be skipped.
I have done this;

```
Order::selectRaw('Date(created_at) as date')->groupBy('date')->get();
```

But keep getting only today's date.

Comment: Have you tried running the sql query directly against the database? Are you sure it works doing `groupBy('date')` using the alias, maybe you need `groupBy('Date(created_at)')`?

Comment: Yes @Joachim. It however returns  a collection of the orders with today's date as date for all of them

Comment: How can it return a collection of orders if you are using GROUP BY?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson MySQL allows aliased expressions to be referenced via the alias in group by clause. Group by can return multiple records, which I would assume are represented as collection.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) ... As your used SQL/PHP code is unlogical/unclear to the questions context it is hard to predict what you need for a solid answer... This also avoids (unrelated/unnecessary) comment "sparring"

Comment: @Shadow, yes I know MySql supports that but does this query language (Eloquent) handle it correctly? And the reason for my second comment was that a GROUP BY on date for records with only todays date should return one row and not a collection.